# Redirect to whole new page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I redirect a user to a new whole page with AngularJS? I'm currently using ng-view, but problem with ng-view is that the other page is "included" in existing page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="gameApp">
<head>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<meta content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type" />
</head>
<body ng-controller="firstPageCtrl">
<div id="layout">
    <div id="topcontent">
    </div>
    <div id="middlecontent">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottomcontent">
        {{"AngularJS"}}
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="js/mastercontroller.js"></script>
</html>
```

As you can see, the page is included between , but I don't want that, I want to redirect the user to a whole new page. How can I do this?

Here is my route:

```
gameApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

    .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/firstpage.html',
            controller  : 'firstPageCtrl'
    })

    .when('/game', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/game.html',
            controller  : 'gameCtrl'
    });

});
```

Comment: angular provides SPA _(single page application)_ structure and you don't want to use that.

Comment: @Jai: What do you mean?

Comment: just curious why you need to do this way, redirecting to a new page.

Comment: You can use `$location` service for this, take a look at the docs.

Comment: @Jai: Because I want to use another type of css-structure at the new page. I use $location.path("/game");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect to external URL, use the $window service.

```
$window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window